# Implement zeroclipboard functionality in twitter bootstrap framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zeroclipboard

I am implementing zeroclipboard functionality in one of my projects using twitter bootstrap framework. My problem is that the code works well under one page but the same code does not work on the other. Although both the page have same header and footer i.e both use same jquery and css. The two page are actually loaded under two different tabs.

Any help will be really appreciated.

The code is

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {  
  setTimeout(function() {
  //create client
  var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
  //event
  clip.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
  clip.setText(document.getElementById('box-content').value);
  });
  clip.addEventListener('complete',function(client,text) {
  alert('copied: ' + text);
});
 //glue it to the button
 clip.glue('copy');
}, 2000);       
   });
```

```
<body>
<textarea name="box-content" id="box-content" rows="5" cols="70">
   Sample text to test clipboard functionality
</textarea>
<p><input style="width:100px; height:40px;" type="button" id="copy" name="copy" value="Copy Text" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should show the code you're using.

Comment: Please check the code